# Keras -- no Dot layer with broadcasting?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras 2.0.2 with the Tensorflow backend. I'm trying to do a batched dot product as part of a layer. I'm not entirely sure how to do this, and none of the things I've seen seem to have the desired functionality.

In particular, I have two layers with shapes (None, 2, 50, 5, 3) and (None, 2, 50, 3, 1), and I want to take the dot product of the '3' dimension, and have that broadcasted over the (None, 2, 50) dimensions -- i.e., I want an output of (None, 2, 50, 5, 1). My use case is very simple: I am computing a matrix (5, 3) and a vector (3, 1) at each timestep of a sequence, and I want to take their dot product at each timestep.

Here is an example showing what I am coming across:

```
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dot, Input

v1 = K.variable(value=np.random.rand(2, 50, 5, 3))
v2 = K.variable(value=np.random.rand(2, 50, 3, 1))
K.batch_dot(v1, v2)  # this works as desired, gives output shape: (2, 50, 5, 1)

x1 = Input((2, 50, 3, 5)) # shape: (None, 2, 50, 3, 5)
x2 = Input((2, 50, 3, 1)) # shape: (None, 2, 50, 3, 1)
Dot(3)([x1, x2]) # output shape is (None, 2, 50, 5, 2, 50, 1)
```

It is strange because the code for the Dot layer (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py) actually uses K.batch_dot, but the behaviour is not the same.

This also seems to contradict the behaviour stated in the docs:
"E.g. if applied to two tensors `a` and `b` of shape `(batch_size, n)`,
    the output will be a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 1)`
    where each entry `i` will be the dot product between
    `a[i]` and `b[i]`."

I've tried other things with no success, e.g. wrapping K.batch_dot in a Lambda layer (which can only take a single input - shouldn't there be an equivalent general-purpose layer taking multiple inputs?) or wrapping the Dot layer in a TimeDistributed Layer (which seems to not work since TimeDistributed can't handle a list as input).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out a couple of ways to do it:

1) If you want to learn the parameters of the matrix you are applying to the vector (which is some function of your input), you can simply apply a TimeDistributed Dense layer with linear activations and no bias.

2) If you want the matrix to be some function of your input (i.e. you want to reshape the output from a layer into a matrix, then apply that to some vector that's a function of your data), you can wrap K.batch_dot in a Lambda layer, where the layer takes as input a single list argument.
i.e. something like: 
`Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_dot(x[0], x[1]))([x1, x2])`. 
The problem with what I was doing before was that I didn't have my inputs as a list, and the Lamdba layer can't take more than 1 input.

There's still the documentation problem -- and also use-case (2) should (IMO) be easier to find. But the above solutions should work.

Comment: Thank you for replying to this question! I had the same issue. It would be great if you clarify (with code) what you mean with the first alternative.